# VS Code Showing missing reference to netstandard for AzureFunctions v1 fsx files

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, azure-functions

The type referenced through xxx is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard'.

[image: Screen shot - run.fsx]

I have just updated VSCode to 1.38.1 and now this error is occurring in all my Azure Functions .fsx files. downgrading to 1.37.1

It makes editing nigh on impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the following preference seems to sort it out

```
"FSharp.fsacRuntime": "net",
```

Comment: Got the same error above, this solution solved it. Upvoted both.  At this point in time the "netcore" option is Experimental so YRMV : http://ionide.io/docs/options/